# How do iterate a sequence with varying starting positions

Tags: scala

Say I have an array:

```
[10,12,20,50]
```

I can iterate though this array like normal which would look at the position at 0, then 1, 2, and 3.

What if I wanted to start an any arbritrary position in the array, and then go through all the numbers in order.

So the other permutations would be:

```
10,12,20,50
12,20,50,10
20,50,10,12
50,10,12,20
```

Is there a general function that would allow me to do this type of sliding iteration?

so looking at the index positions from the above it would be:

```
0,1,2,3
1,2,3,0
2,3,0,1
3,0,1,2
```

It would be great if some languages have this built in, but I want to know the algorithm to do this also so I understand.

Comment: The general algorithm is quite trivial: `concat(i..n, 0..i)`. Are you asking specifically about Scala `Seq`?

Comment: What do you mean with iterate? Like, you were thinking just of a `map` or something that would change the order? - Or you just want to rotate the `Seq` and produce a new `Seq` with that new order?

Answer (score 2):

Let's iterate over an array.

```
val arr = Array(10, 12, 20, 50)

for (i <- 0 to arr.length - 1) {
    println(arr(i))
}
```

With output:

```
10
12
20
50
```

Pretty basic.

What about:

```
val arr = Array(10, 12, 20, 50)

for (i <- 2 to (2 + arr.length - 1)) {
    println(arr(i))
}
```

Oops. Out of bounds. But what if we modulo that index by the length of the array?

```
val arr = Array(10, 12, 20, 50)

for (i <- 2 to (2 + arr.length - 1)) {
    println(arr(i % arr.length))
}
```

```
20
50
10
12
```

Now you just need to wrap it up in a function that replaces `2` in that example with an argument.

Answer (score 2):

There is no language builtin. There is a similar method [permutations](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/SeqOps.html#permutations:Iterator%5BC%5D), but it will generate all permutations without the order, which doesn't really fit your need.

Your requirement can be implemented with a simple algorithm where you just concatenates two slices:

```
def orderedPermutation(in: List[Int]): Seq[List[Int]] = {
  for(i <- 0 until in.size) yield
    in.slice(i, in.size) ++ in.slice(0, i)
}

orderedPermutation(List(10,12,20,50)).foreach(println)
```

Working code [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/HL7tkvZSROaUMVxqgUyArQ)